# Design circuit with two OP AMP and one voltage source

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, current

[image]

I'm having trouble with this problem. I'm supposed to design this circuit in such a way that the value of R will make the current ix = 10 Amps. Any ideas? I have just no idea where to begin for this one.

Comment: You're sure the output of the lower op-amp is not supposed to be connected to something?

Comment: A good place to start would be to solve for the voltage at the output of the top op-amp. And yeah, what's the deal with the bottom op-amp?

Comment: FWIW, as it stands, I'm fairly confident that no value of R will set ix = 10 A. And with ideal op-amps, connecting the outputs of the op-amps together will result in problems... Perhaps there is something missing?

Comment: @ThePhoton yes you are all right. sorry i drew it wrong. the lower amp is supposed to be connected in between the R resistor and the 25 Ohm resistor. Sorry for that. So basically theres supposed to be a line at the end of the bottom OP AMP connecting it to the whole circuit.

Comment: @ThePhoton I've updated the picture

Comment: What's going to happen here is one of the two op-amps is going to catch fire. The upper op-amp is going to try to force the output node to -50 V, but you are trying to make the lower op-amp force it to +100 V.

Comment: If this was an exercise given to you, are you sure you're showing the 10 ohm resistor connected the same way it was in the original?

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes I'm sure its correct. I can upload the picture of the problem itself as well. And what do you mean its going to catch fire? I'm still very lost.

Comment: The upper op-amp is trying to force the output node to -50 V. The lower op-amp is trying to force it to +100 V. These are op-amps capable of producing 10 A at 100 V (1 kW). If you try to do this experimentally, be sure to video it and share it with us.

Comment: @ThePhoton So is there a value that we can find for R? I am not actually doing this experimentally, just theoretically as a problem.

Comment: There are many different schematic conventions.  It's not my favorite but some choose to show wires crossing by not allowing connected wires to cross.  Only Ts are allowed.  I'm guessing the lower amplifier is not connected to the 10 Ohm load but only the 25 Ohm and R.  Can you tell me if this is right or wrong.  Also the convention of putting the inverting input on the bottom for non-inverting amplifiers is one I like because it leads to fewer lines crossing.  I've used several schematic capture programs the provide both symbols for the same part just for that reason.

Comment: @owg60, even if we assume the crossing wires are not connected, the problem remains unsolvable, because that means the upper op-amp is open-loop and there's no control of the output voltage at all.

Comment: Is this another one of those school examples that totally misrepresents reality?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not solvable.

If we assume ideal op-amps, the upper op-amp is trying to force the output voltage to -50 V, producing -5 A through the load resistor. If the lower op-amp tries to force it to a different voltage, that is a contradiction in your model --- i.e., you can't assume ideal op-amps here. To get a plausible answer, you must specify some output resistance for the op-amps.

If we assume real op-amps, the problem is simply not realistic. 10 A through 10 ohms requires 100 V, and results in 1 kW delivered to the load. This is not feasible with real op-amps. Furthermore the conflict in outputs between the two op-amps would (very briefly) result in vastly higher currents being produced until one or the other of the two op-amps incinerated itself.

In general, you should not design circuits where the outputs of two amplifiers are connected directly together. They will not be analyzable by simple models since their behavior will depend on non-ideal behavior of the components. And in practice they will tend to damage themselves when turned on.

Comment: Thank you. I just had no idea what was going on. And I didn't choose this problem, my professor created it as a practice problem for us so I assumed there would be an answer for R.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhuo16.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I think you are right, this is the problem that was intended to be asked. But I asked OP "are you sure you're showing the 10 ohm resistor connected the same way it was in the original?" and the reply was "Yes I'm sure its correct."

Comment: @ThePhoton Apparently this is how you are supposed to do it:

Now we have already calculated the K of top circuit as K=-5, Vout(top)=-5*10V=-50V, and the K of bottom circuit as K=(10+R)/R, Vout(bottom)=K*10V=(10+R)V. Since these two OP AMP share a common end, the output voltage driving the resistor should be the summation of Vout(top) and Vout(bottom) as (R-40)V. It’s easy to obtain R=140.